# Using jquery to hijack form values

Tags: jquery, html, forms, model-view-controller

I'm attempting to check my form values before submitting using jquery.  When I attempt to check the values using alert() the values show as undefined.

```
 <form id="test" method ="get">           
 username<br>
 <br>
 <input type="text" name="firstfield">
 password 
 <input type="text" name="secondfield">
 <input type="submit" id="_click" value="click">
 </form>    
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#_click').click(function () {
        var uname = $('#firstfield').val();
        var pass = $('#secondfield').val();
        alert(uname);
        alert(pass);
    });//click     
});//documentready
</script>
```

Comment: `firstfield`  and `secondfield` are value of name attribute while # is used for selecting by value of ID attribute  [Working](http://jsfiddle.net/ankit2038/w2pjpvbu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your input values to this

```
 <input type="text" name="firstfield" id="firstfield">
 password 
 <input type="text" name="secondfield" id="secondfield">
```

This bit of code:

```
$('#firstfield').val();
$('#secondfield').val();
```

, is looking for elements with id of `firstfield` and `secondfield` respectively.

Your `<input>` elements don't have an id, so they will always be undefined.

A working fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0h1cfrpm/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#_click').click(function () {
        var uname = $('#firstfield').val();
        var pass = $('#secondfield').val();
        alert(uname);
        alert(pass);
    });    
});
```

Comment: Thanks all.  I see now that this won't work as expected without an ID attribute.  I've corrected my code and it now works.

Answer (score 1):

You can **attribute selectors** in your JavaScript

```
var uname = $('[name=firstfield]').val();
var pass = $('[name=secondfield]').val();
```

This code is *actually* checking the `name` attribute of the **element**.

---

Your input elements don't have an `id` attribute so the browser can't find them *(`#` is `id`)*

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blue1086/q2aezo50/)

---

**Attribute selectors** and **CSS3 Selectors** are *very* useful, learn more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)